# command shopify theme serve show error when i'm the owner

Tags: shopify

i try to use command shopify theme serve in my project. My account is owner and i also create a staff account with all sensitive permissions. But the terminal always return  `You can't use Shopify CLI with development stores if you only have Partner staff member access. If you want to use Shopify CLI to work on a development store, then you should be the store owner or create a staff account on the store.` . 
 How i can fix this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had a plethora of issues with Shopify CLI, so I can help here. This has happened when I have been logged in for a while. I will need more information, but will provide a few catch-all solutions.

1.Are you using a developer account, or are you logged into a store? Try logging out and logging in again as the owner account.

2. What version are you using?

```
shopify version
```

3. Have you tried logging out and logging back into your store? This usually rectifies it.

```
shopify logout
shopify login --store=[your .myshopifyURL]
```

4. Are you using ruby or homebrew? I have found ruby to be much more stable, and it allows to switch between Shopify CLI versions.
5. Try switching to a previous shopify version 2.20 or 2.19 if you continue seeing issues. Again, this will need to be done with ruby, as homebrew does not allow any version backtracking.

Edit: make sure your login command looks like this:

```
shopify login --store=verizon.myshopify.com
```

You can paste this link from shopify admin, as it is the same link.

Answer (score 1):

As of Shopify CLI version 3.49.2, the following method worked for me when I needed to switch stores:

**Shopify CLI Logout**

```
> shopify auth logout
```

**Shopify CLI Login:**

```
> shopify theme pull --store=verizon
```

`example: https://admin.shopify.com/store/verizon/`